# Is it possible to add a custom event to Vue 2's 'on' directive?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to add a 'clickaway' event to Vue's global 'on' directive in order to use it in the Vue template like so:

```html
<div v-on:clickaway="someMethod">

</div>
```

So the JavaScript would look something like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.directive('on', {
// Default 'On' functionality here

// My method that checks if 'clickaway' has been passed in as an argument
});
```

Is this at all possible?

Edit:

To hopefully clarify what I'm going for, I've currently got this working how I want it to in a directive:

```js
Vue.directive('clickaway', {
    bind(element, { expression }, { context }) {
        element.clickAwayEvent = event => {
            if (!(element === event.target || element.contains(event.target))) {
                context[expression](event);
            }
        };

         document.body.addEventListener('click', element.clickAwayEvent);
    },

    unbind(element) {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', element.clickAwayEvent);
    },
});
```

And the markup:

```html
<div v-clickaway="closeDropdown"></div>
```

But rather than in a custom directive I want to be able to write it as so:

```html
<div v-on:clickaway="closeDropdown"></div>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); are you trying to add a custom (synthetic) event to every `div`, or do you really need to hook into Vue's events logic to run some code when *any* event fires? There's no restriction to listening to custom events on native dom elements using the `v-on` syntax. Note that custom events on native dom elements are distinct from custom component events as linked to above (see also https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on).

Comment: @MichalLevý not what I'm looking for - a clickaway event is unique in that it needs to be accessible by all components so the typical emit to parent -> listen for event paradigm isn't really appropriate. The way I've done it in the past is using an event bus to emit to an invisible overlay component that would listen for a click to display and also held a click event which would close itself if clicked on but that was a bit messy. Currently I've got it working with a directive (e.g. v-clickaway) that I can use anywhere but I'm trying to make the syntax identical to that of any other event

Comment: @chipit24 hopefully my above response clarifies some. Your link is definitely more of what I'm going for; however, I'm not sure it fully solves my problem. I'm looking for the root Vue instance to listen to a custom event firing from anywhere in the code, with a handler that essentially checks if the dropdown component that I assigned the event to is the target, and if it isn't, to fire the method that I passed in. So the code on the component will be `<div @clickaway="closeDropdown">markup here</div>`, and Vue will recognise when to execute that clickaway code

Comment: @chipit24 I've edited my question for clarification

Comment: You cannot "extend" existing directive (as "v-on"). Also Vue events do not bubble as standard browser events. If it works for you just use `v-clickaway` approach...

Comment: @MichalLevý Ah, that sucks. Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As answered by MichalLevý, what I was trying to do is not possible and the best alternative is to go with the directive approach.